# user.getIdToken is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, error-handling, firebase-authentication

```
export const editEmail = async (newEmail) => {
  await updateEmail(auth, newEmail);
}; // my code in firebase
```

```
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      console.log(newEmail);
      await editEmail(newEmail);
      Setmessage("update email berhasil");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };// my code handle submit
```

the error :

```
TypeError: user.getIdToken is not a function
     at updateEmailOrPassword (account_info.ts:127:1)
     at updateEmail (account_info.ts:93:1)
     at editEmail (firebase.js:46:1)
     at handlerSubmit (editEmail.js:34:1)
     at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4163:1)
     at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4212:1)
     at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4276:1)
     at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4290:1)
     at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9040:1)
     at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9071:1)
```

i want to update my email using service firebase, that is updateEmail. how to solve it?

Comment: I don't see where you are calling `user.getIdToken` or the definition of `updateEmailOrPassword` that you can see in the error message.  Are you showing the relevant code?

Comment: thanks to try help me to solve the code dude, it's solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`updateEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#updateemail) method has a signature of `updateEmail(user, email)`.

In your current code, you are instead calling `updateEmail(auth, email)`, which should actually be `updateEmail(auth.currentUser, email)` instead.

**Note:** The `updateEmail` and `updatePassword` operations are sensitive and require the user to have recently signed in, so make sure your code handles when Firebase rejects the request.

Comment: thanks bro, you solve my code. but sorry your note i don't understand clearly. is your note mean, to validation input, like have 2 input, and first input value is curent email, and second input is new email. so if first input wrong tell the user? and i if true updateEmail?, CMIIW cause my english so bad.

Comment: @Excell Use `updateEmail(auth.currentUser, email)`. My note was added to highlight the following point: To successfully change the user's email, that user must have logged into their account recently. For example, you can't change the user's email if the last time they logged in was last week. Most websites ask the user for their password to authorise the change of email. The password is then used to log in again (reauthenticate) and then update the email once logged in.

Comment: owh i see thanks for explaination, this really help me